# java.util.UUID : UUID.randomUUID() duplicate UUIDs with Windows + QEMU

Tags: uuid, qemu, entropy

We are running several VMs with Windows on several Ubuntu Machines with QEMU+KVM.
These VMs are created/destroyed several times per hour, with different MAC/IP Addresses.

Every once in a while, a java process will return the same `UUID.randomUUID()` as previous VM (from the same/different hypervisor). For example, a Windows VM we created over a month ago returned the same `UUID.randomUUID()` as a VM created just now.

The only reason we can think of is a lack of entropy? Is there a way to seed the entropy for `java.util.UUID` to prevent this from happening?